# Where is the system files in android lollipop onwards?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have recently downloaded lollipop custom rom for my phone and when i go to the system part of the downloaded file, I can only find buildprop and nothing else. Prior to lollipop it used to have system etc bin and many more.

Where can we find these files in lollipop?
Any help  will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: its still there in my android (using cyanogenmod 12.1) are you sure you're rooted?

Comment: nope not rooted. Ive downloaded cm12.1 for galaxy grand 2(SM-G7102). Basically the rom is not rooted. How can i make changes?

Comment: go to developer options, then turn on your root

Comment: done.. what next?? sorry I'm still a noob. Venturing into android development.

Comment: just open it with file manager with root permission

Comment: No. How can I access it on my computer to port a rom?

Comment: You can easily access them over a usb connection using [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) [pull](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/adb-push-and-pull-Command.html). Of course, root will have to be allowed for adb—in the same manner you allowed apps—if you'd l like to access restricted partitions (such as /system).

Comment: What if I want to edit a ROM which I download? How do I give su access to unrooted ROM ? Will I be able to access it giving adb root? Or anything else has to be done?

Comment: I haven't built a rom yet, but I think it's as simple as including a `su` binary, and a GUI frontend for permission grant/denial for building your own. You can indeed give `su` access to a stock rom, though the process is not standard. Splitting permission access between apps and adb is CyanogenMod only as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for the info!